How to Use Bluetooth in a React Native App Without Violating App Store Guidelines?
Requesting Bluetooth Access Prompt
Requesting Notification Access Promp
I’m building a React Native app that uses Bluetooth functionality exclusively to connect an IoT device to the internet. For this, I’m using the react-native-ble-plx library, which prompts the user to allow Bluetooth access. However, my app was rejected from the App Store with the following feedback:
The app does not use App Tracking Transparency (ATT) to request the user’s permission before collecting data used to track them. Instead, the app displays a custom prompt that requests the user to allow tracking. Apps need to receive the user’s permission through the AppTrackingTransparency framework before collecting data used to track them. Requesting permission with a custom prompt is not appropriate. No ATT was found concerning access to Bluetooth.
few clarifications:
1. My app does not collect or share any user data with third parties.
2. Bluetooth functionality is solely used for connecting the IoT device and does not involve any tracking.
3. I did not explicitly add any custom prompt for tracking; I’m only using the default react-native-ble-plx functionality.
Questions:
•Does accessing Bluetooth require ATT permission if no tracking or data sharing occurs?
•How can I clarify this to Apple during the review process?
•Are there any steps I should take in my app to ensure compliance with App Store guidelines regarding Bluetooth usage?

App tracking transparency is nothing to do with Bluetooth. It refers specifically to accessing the advertising identifier (IDFA). You should check for any libraries you have included that access this.  In general should not show any dialogs that discuss "tracking" outside of the ones built in to iOS. There is a Bluetooth privacy permission dialog that is shown when you use core Bluetooth.
